# What do you call a "hidden" shape denoted by a dashed line?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

Is there a word (or short phrase, preferably two words) that describes a shape which is not visible, but whose presence is indicated (e.g. in an illustration, by a dashed line)? Particularly, an object that is behind the viewer?

So far, the closest words I've come up with are: silhouette, phantom, occlusion, overlay.

---

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

[image: example]

Here, the objects (conceptually, skylights in a map of a warehouse) are represented by a dashed line, but an umbrella in a video game that turns transparent when the player walks under it would be another example. (Note that the helpful red arrows are only pointing to two of the four such objects. This is because I am lazy, not because the ones on the left are somehow different.)

Comment: Can you post an example picture of this thing?

Comment: I'd use phantom for pretty much anything that is rendered in minimal detail and clutter. In the plan view of a sailboat interior, You might have deck hatches, skylights, and ventilators shown as phantoms. In a piping and wiring arrangement, you might have cabinetry, furniture, and fixtures as phantoms. Show a closed door's open position as a phantom.

Comment: http://woodcarvingillustrated.com/scrollsawer/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/07/438_Fig.6.jpg

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that a phantom is different from a hidden line obscured by an object that is in front of the line.

Comment: @KannE, more broadly speaking, I'm thinking of objects that are rendered differently because they would otherwise hide what is considered the "important" information.

Comment: @PhilSweet, care to write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly: When one object occludes another, you want to the occluding object to become transparent to reveal the occluded object. Like this:

[image: under an umbrella]

I’m going to go with *see-through view*, taking cues from this loosely-related whitepaper: [Visualization Methods for Outdoor See-Through Vision](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.113.2640&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I’ll let you muck around in there for more ideas, but here’s the opening sentence:

> Visualizing occluded objects is a useful applications of Mixed Reality
> (MR), which we call “see-through vision.” For this application, it is
> important to display occluded objects in such a manner that they can
> be recognized intuitively by the user.

*X-ray view* might work too. If you need to refer to the actual dotted line, perhaps: *wireframe*.

Comment: I'm not asking about the presentation technique, but the object itself. "Wireframe" might work, though, or at least is on the right track.

Comment: @Matthew: Can you construct an example sentence in which this word would be used?

Comment: "____s are rendered as dashed outlines"? (Or "___ objects ...") My actual, ultimate use is trying to come up with a reasonable CSS class name for these critters, so it's not going to be used in a sentence, and while I feel like there *ought* to be a noun for these (I may be imagining that), an adjective might be acceptable. Note that it doesn't need to be a single word, although 3+ words is probably too clunky.

Comment: @Matthew: You can roll your own noun from an adjective. How about *See-throughs are rendered as dashed outlines*? .see-through { outline:#000 dashed 2px; }

Answer (score 0):

I believe that these can be adequately referred to as a 'dotted outline' shapes. An online search for 'dotted outline' seems to yield images very similar to your example.

Comment: It might improve the answer if you included the best example or two from those you've found.

Comment: "dotted outline" isn't a single word, though...